# Is a Pokemon's entry in the Pokedex removed when it is released?

Tags: pokemon-series

If you release a Pokemon does it get removed from your Pokedex?

Answer (score 10):

Of course not, when you release a Pokemon it's only removed from the box in the PC.
When a Pokemon is recorded in the Pokedex it can never be lost, even if it's traded or released.